# App thinks its running on 3.5 inch iPhone when it is on 4 inch

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am developing app for both 3.5 and 4 inch screens. However, suddenly on the simulator the screen size became 320 * 480 even when I am running 4-inch iPhone simulator.

I put this in AppDelegate file and it printed 320.000000, 480.000000...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    NSLog(@"%f, %f", [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);

    ...
}
```

I'm not sure which setting in Xcode (if any) that I accidentally touched that made it like this. All my .xib files are set to 4-inch retina. Does anyone came across this before?

Comment: also check that you have Default-h568 file in the project for iPhone 4inches

Comment: It turns out when I renamed my project folder the default icons and launch images links are broken - once they are fixed everything worked again! Thank you!

Comment: @JayiODroid or you should add this as an answer so it can be accepted and the question closed off. Don't leave the solution hiding in the comments!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please check that you have Default-h568 file in the project for iPhone 4inches.

Answer (score 1):

About default applications created in Xcode 6.0, try this:

Project properties -> App Icons and Launch Images -> Launch Image Source -> Use Asset Catalog -> Images, Migrate

After this project will be displayed correctly on 4-inch iOS 7 devices.