# Objective C: SpriteKit - wrong frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, frame

I created an image for retina resolution for 4 inch screen with the size of 640x1136px. It didn't scale properly. To debug, I decided to let the code print out the width and height of `self.view.frame`. The results were

`width: 320`
`height: 480`

this is incorrect as height should be 568 points (1136 px). What is the deal with wrong frame size in objective-c spriteKit?

Edit:

Code posted below

Below @implementation

`UIImageView* menuImage;`

in `(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view`

```
menuImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuImage"]];
menuImage.frame = self.view.frame;
NSLog(@"height: %f || width: %f", self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width);
```

Edit 2:

submitting the results of few tests

```
ScreenSize: {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
SuperViewSize: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
SelfSize: {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not accidentally checking it on 3.5 device/simulator or manually changing the view size somewhere?

Comment: Yes. It's a completely new project so I am certain I'm not changing the view size anywhere. I'm testing it on my iPhone 5s physical device.

I'm adding the code in case it will help.

Comment: Can you please add the following `NSLog` statements and post their values? `NSLog(@"ScreenSize: %@", NSStringFromCGRect([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]));` `NSLog(@"SuperViewSize: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.superview.bounds));` `NSLog(@"SelfSize: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));`

Comment: Absolutely. The log printed that:

Edit: I'll post them in the answer since its hardly readable here.

I don't quite understand what this proves.

Comment: Can you run it on a 4-inch simulator and see if you get the same results?

Comment: I just did that. I ran it on iPhone 5s simulator and as you asked, it stated the exactly same results.

Comment: Please try, on the 'Navigator' on the left side, go to 'Images.xcassets' -> 'LaunchImage' and make sure you have a 4-inch launch image.

Comment: I didn't have a launch image yet since the app is in early stage, but nevertheless, I put the `menuImage` which has the correct size as a retina 2x launchImage since you asked. It didn't change anything. I don't know why it should either.

Comment: I agree it sound weird, but have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353455/app-thinks-its-running-on-3-5-inch-iphone-when-it-is-on-4-inch

Comment: You led me to the answer. The app wouldn't use launchImage, but instead the new iOS launchFile. I changed that in the settings of the project, removed launchImage imageSet, added it there again and now it works. Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: You welcome mate. I've learned from it myself incase I'll run into that issue in the future :-). Maybe you should post your result as an answer here, for those who may encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of AMI289 (see comments), we figured out how to repair this.

First, I went to the project settings, and under General I removed the text from "Launch Screen File". Then, I added Launch Image Source. Afterwards, I removed the launch image set file and created new one. This made the `menuImage` fit the whole screen in correct resolution.

Note: This might work only when using launch image instead of launch file, since part of the process was to remove the text in launch screen file textfield. However, I'm not sure which part of the process actually fixed the problem so it might work anyway.